# Как передать длину массива из JavaScript в PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Есть массив `let arr = ["a", "b", "c"]` 
Хочу передать длину массива в переменную PHP. Говорят, что лучше использовать Ajax.

Comment: Используйте Ajax.

Comment: больше подробностей. чего куда и когда надо передать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, описывайте свой вопрос более детальнее. Если это какой-то статический массив, будет лучше, если он будет у вас храниться не в JS, а в PHP. Из PHP передаёте его на страницу, а на бэкэнде делаете с ним что хотите

```php
<?php
$a = ["a", "b", "c"];

echo "
<script>
    var a = " . json_encode($a) . ";
</script>";
```